# TestNG: priority of @BeforeClass and @BeforeTest

Tags: selenium, testng

I have been using TestNG and having problems with two annotations, `@BeforeTest` and `@BeforeClass`. I would like to know if both are applied which will run first ?

Answer (score 12):

**Answer**: Method annotated with `@BeforeTest` will be invoked before than the method annotated with `@BeforeClass`.

**`TestNG` annotations execution order in reference to `@Test` and description**:

1. **@BeforeSuite**: The annotated method will be run before all tests in
       this suite have run.
2. **@BeforeTest**: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the
    tag is run.
3. **@BeforeGroups**: The list of groups that this
   configuration method will run before. This method is guaranteed to
   run shortly
       before the first test method that belongs to any of these groups is
       invoked.
4. **@BeforeClass**: The annotated method will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked.
5. **@BeforeMethod**: The annotated method will be run before each test method.
6. **@Test**: The test method or class
7. **@AfterMethod**: The annotated method will be run after each test method.
8. **@AfterClass**: The annotated method will be run after all the test methods in the current class have been run.
9. **@AfterGroups**: The list of groups that this configuration method will run after. This method is guaranteed to run shortly
   after the last test method that belongs to any of these groups is
   invoked.
10. **@AfterTest**: The annotated method will be run after all the test methods belonging to the classes inside the  tag have
    run.
11. **@AfterSuite**: The annotated method will be run after all tests in this suite have run.

> There are various other annotations provided by `TestNG` and different
>   types of attributes/parameters can be passed to these annotations. For
>   more information on `TestNG` annotations [follow this link](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations)

Comment: @Adam Grunt if you feel this answer clarifies your doubts then you can accept it so that it can help others too to find the best answer easily.

Comment: I confused between `@BeforeTest` to `@BeforeMethod`, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

**Annotations execution order**:

1. BeforeSuite
2. BeforeTest
3. BeforeClass
4. BeforeMethod
5. Test
6. AfterGroups
7. AfterClass
8. AfterTest

You can check with the pseudo code:

```
public class TestAnnotationsPriorityOrder {

public int i=0;


@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite(){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i+"::BeforeSuite");
}

@AfterSuite
public void afterSuite(){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i+"::AfterSuite");
}

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest(){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i+"::BeforeTest");
}

@AfterTest
public void afterTest(){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i+"::AfterTest");
}


@BeforeGroups
public void beforeGroups(){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i+"::BeforeGroups");
}

@AfterGroups
public void afterGroups(){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i+"::AfterGroups");
}


@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass(){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i+"::BeforeClass");
}

@AfterClass
public void afterClass(){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i+"::AfterClass");
}


@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i+"::BeforeMethod");
}

@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i+"::AfterGroups");
}


@Test
public void TestMethod(){
    i++;
    System.out.println(i+"::Test");
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before test first and then before class.

`@BeforeTest`: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the `<test>` tag is run.

`@BeforeClass`: The annotated method will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked.
 http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Comment: ok and what about after class and after test? after test gets executed first?

Comment: yes. check this snippets and you can get the idea, http://pastebin.com/sp8kceK3 line 1 to 45 abstract class, 45-76, 2 classes with 2 test each, and from 76 to 94 the testng.xml. The last is the console output. I read wrong, check the updated answer and the snippets.